# Как сделать что бы пользователь не мог ввести буквы?

Tags: javascript

```
while (true) {
  var UserDigit = prompt('Введите числа через запятую ');
  var arr = UserDigit.split(",")

  var sum = 0;
  var work = 1;
  for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    sum += parseInt(arr[i])
    work *= parseInt(arr[i])
  }
  if (!isNaN(arr[i])) {
    alert('Вы ввели не корректные данные. Повторите,пожалуйста,ввод', '')
  } else if (isNaN(arr[i])) {
    break
  } else {
    alert('Error')
  }

}
document.write('Сумма чисел равна: ' + sum + '<br>')
document.write('Произведение чисел равно: ' + work + '<br>')
document.write('Среднее арифметическое равно: ' + sum / 2 + '<br>')
```

Comment: Проверку на что надо сделать? Можно реализовать обработку исключений `try{...}catch(....){.....}`

Comment: У Вас проверки `isNaN(arr[i])` вне цикла. А это подозрительно.

Comment: На кой плодить одинаковые вопросы?

Comment: Вы с циклами запустались у вас один цикл в другом, тут этого не надо и работать не будет, так же нету критерия выхода из цикла.

Comment: Не надо задавать один и тот же вопрос несколько раз.

Comment: Спасибо Дмитрий, а то как то запутался я ведь только начинаю учить JS

Comment: @Евгений, если  помогли... Прими ответ...  Не хорошо оставлять людей без внимания...

Comment: А как я с удовольствием подскажите

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var UserDigit = prompt('Введите числа через запятую ');
var arr = UserDigit.split(",")

var sum = 0;
var work = 1;
var error = false;

for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  var num = parseInt(arr[i]);

  if (isNaN(num)) {
    error = true;
    break;
  }

  sum += num;
  work *= num;
}

if (!error) {
  document.write('Сумма чисел равна: ' + sum + '<br>')
  document.write('Произведение чисел равно: ' + work + '<br>')
  document.write('Среднее арифметическое равно: ' + sum / arr.length + '<br>')
} else {
  alert('Вы ввели не корректные данные. Повторите,пожалуйста,ввод', '');
}
```

Comment: Автору: вроде бы переменная i будет существовать вне цикла со значением `i=arr.length-1`, так что вычисление среднего арифметического будет следующим: `sum/(i+1)`

Comment: Среднее арифметическое будет просто: sum / (i)

Comment: Сделал код более красивым и вставил правильный подсчёт среднего арифметического (вначале я оставлял авторский вариант).

Comment: И да, можно было на `i` разделить, это тоже правильное решение.

Answer (score 0):

```
while(true){var arr = prompt("Введите числа через запятую").split(",")
    arr = arr.filter(function(arr)
    {return arr}); 
    var sum=0;
    var work=1;
    var prov = arr.join('')
    if (isNaN(prov)||!isNaN(arr[i])){alert('Вы ввели не корректные данные. Повторите,пожалуйста,ввод', '')}
        else if(!isNaN(prov)){break}    
}  
for (var i=0; i<arr.length; i++){
    sum+=parseInt(arr[i]);
    work*=parseInt(arr[i]);
}


  document.write('Сумма чисел равна: ' + sum + '<br>')
  document.write('Произведение чисел равно: ' + work + '<br>')
  document.write('Среднее арифметическое равно: ' + sum / arr.length + '<br>')
```